# share private key [blockchain]

Tags: private-key

What happend if I share my private key with my partner? Can we spend bitcoins together without collisons from the same wallet? 
Me and my friend are using BlockChain.info - what will happend when we import same private key? Can this destroy this wallet?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the client you use, this could be a very bad idea, the reason being that some clients send change to new addresses while others send the change back to the sending address.

If you use an online wallet such as blockchain.info you should be fine as it sends change back to itself, and in this case you'll both be online so your clients will always have an up to date list of the transactions for that address.

The chance of having a collision (aka: Double spend) is very low as this requires you to both spend the same transactions within seconds of each other and if you are both using the same online wallet it would probably need to be done near simultaneously.

Remember that the private key fully controls ownership of the coins (hence being private) so you need to fully trust anyone with knowledge of it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea

If you get hacked, it may lead to distrust between you and your partner, since both of you may not believe that it wasn't the other person that misappropriated the funds.

Better to use a 2 of 3 multisig with a centralized provider holding the 3rd key, or otherwise manage the 3rd key in a way that prevents these types of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a multi-signature wallet or a wallet that supports shared access without revealing the private keys. Multi-signature wallets require multiple private keys to authorize transactions, which can provide better security and control in shared ownership scenarios.